# Find all natural $n$ , such that $f^{(n)}$ exists on all of $\Bbb{R}$ , for a defined function.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Exercise:

> Define $f$ on $\Bbb{R}$ by
>   $$
> f(x):= 
> \begin{cases}
> x^3& x\ge0\\\
> 0 &x<0
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find all natural $n$ , such that $f^{(n)}$ exists on all of $\Bbb{R}$.

Attempt: When $x < 0$, we have $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$ for all natural $n$.  Then consider when $x \ge 0$.

Then take $f(x) = x^3$.

Then by definition $f'(a) = \lim_{h \to0 } [f(a + h) - f(a)]/h$ .

Then using the definition and substituting , we have $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to0} h^2 = 0$.

Thus $f'(0)$ exists.

Then $f''(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} [f'(a + h) - f'(a)]/h  = \lim_{h\to 0}  3h = 0$.

Then similarly for  $f'''(0) = 6$.

Can someone please help me finish? I don't know what to conclude. 
Any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x>0$ you have also $f'(x)=3x^2$, $f''(x)=6x$, $f'''(x)=6$, hence there is discontinuity of $f'''$ in 0 and $f^{(4)}(0)$ doesn't exist. Moreover, even simple graphic of $f''$ shows that also $f'''(0)$ doesn't exist, so you should correct your proof.

Your mistake is probably based on assumption, that derivative is continuous, but it is easy to verify, that one sided derivatives of 3rd order are not equal in 0.

Comment: There is a discontinuity because the limit is not zero? In addition, n is only defined when n = 1,2? When n >= 3 it would not be defined? thanks

Comment: @user30493 Because right-hand limit is 6 and left-hand limit is zero. Yes. there is only $f'(0)$  and $f''(0)$.